# What does it mean to fulfill a commitment?

Tags: support

On Area51, it mentions 0% have currently fulfilled their commitment. What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Users elsewhere have pieced together a picture of what it means to fulfill your commitment, here: [How to "follow through" on an area51 proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103294/how-to-follow-through-on-an-area51-proposal).

From the [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#commitment):

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions…

Comment: I find it hard to believe that we're at 0% given that @trent.sol has answered quite a bit more than a few questions. Maybe the key is to start _asking_ some.

Comment: @steveuscher No commitments are fulfilled until a Stack Exchange site goes to public beta.